# "unknown keyword platform" when restoring in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget, .net-core, .net-core-rc2

I'm converting a project from .NET Core RC1 to RC2. I've installed the  Visual Studio tooling preview package and updated the VS Nuget plugin to the latest version.

This is a test project, so I need to add `Microsoft.NETCore.App` to my `project.json` per the [library guide](http://dotnet.github.io/docs/core-concepts/libraries/libraries-with-cli.html#how-to-test-libraries-on-net-core). It looks like this:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "dotnet-test-xunit": "1.0.0-rc2-build10015",
    "FluentAssertions": "4.2.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "type": "platform",
      "version": "1.0.0-rc2-3002702"
    },
    "xunit": "2.1.0"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [ "dotnet", "portable-net45+win8" ]
    }
  },
  "testRunner": "xunit",
}
```

The project restores and builds on the command line (`dotnet restore/build`). However, when Visual Studio tries to restore packages, I get this error:

```
PATH=.\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Web\External;%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Web\External\git
C:\Users\Nate\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc2-20221\bin\dnx.exe "C:\Users\Nate\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc2-20221\bin\lib\Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling\Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling.dll" restore "C:\Users\Nate\Documents\stormpath-dotnet-config\test\Stormpath.Configuration.Test"
Microsoft .NET Development Utility Clr-x86-1.0.0-rc2-20221
  CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
Restoring packages for C:\Users\Nate\Documents\stormpath-dotnet-config\test\Stormpath.Configuration.Test\project.json
----------
C:\Users\Nate\Documents\stormpath-dotnet-config\test\Stormpath.Configuration.Test\project.json(0,0): Error: Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.FileFormatException: unknown keyword platform ---> System.InvalidOperationException: unknown keyword platform
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.LibraryDependencyType.Parse(String keyword)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.ProjectReader.PopulateDependencies(String projectPath, IList`1 results, JsonObject settings, String propertyName, Boolean isGacOrFrameworkReference)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.ProjectReader.ReadProject(Stream stream, String projectName, String projectPath, ICollection`1 diagnostics)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Project.TryGetProject(String path, Project& project, ICollection`1 diagnostics)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Project.TryGetProject(String path, Project& project, ICollection`1 diagnostics)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling.RestoreCommand.<RestoreForProject>d__69.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling.RestoreCommand.<>c__DisplayClass68_0.<<Execute>b__2>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling.RestoreCommand.<Execute>d__68.MoveNext()
----------
Restore failed
unknown keyword platform
NuGet Config files used:
    C:\ProgramData\NuGet\Config\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Offline.config
    C:\Users\Nate\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\nuget.config
Feeds used:
    https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/
    C:\Users\Nate\Documents\LocalNuget
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\
```

Obviously the `"type": "platform"` property is throwing it off, but shouldn't this work with the latest tooling release?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Tl;dr** - Update or replace `global.json` with the `version` value below.

Also, make sure that NuGet is [updated](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/installing-nuget#updating-nuget-in-visual-studio). (Thanks for the tip, gigi!)

This error is caused by an old tooling version in `global.json`. If the value hasn't been updated (easy to miss when migrating projects), this error will inexplicably be thrown even with the newest tooling installed.

Your `global.json` might look like this for an RC1-era project:

```
{
  "projects": [ "src", "test" ],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-rc1-update1"
  }
}
```

For .NET Core 1.0 RTM, it should look like:

```
{
  "projects": [ "src", "test" ],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-preview2-003121"
  }
}
```

The tricky part is that even `version: 1.0.0-rc2-20221` **will not** work! `version: 1.0.0-preview2-003121` is the correct value as of now. The `global.json` file above will restore and compile with both Visual Studio and `dotnet build`/`dotnet run`.

Comment: Damien Edwards used "version": "1.0.0-rc2-002392"... is that out of date https://github.com/aspnet/live.asp.net/commit/d67e1d09cdca8acdba7e2cefa5061a5fb279ba5d?
Where is this documented?

Comment: I'm going to just delete the global.json file and see how that goes.

Comment: @Aligned: I'm not sure if that works or not. Can you restore in VS with the value Damien used?

Comment: VS recreated the global.json with what you had after I deleted it.

Comment: I have version `1.0.0-preview1-002702` and I get `Error: unknown keyword platform` when I run `dnx . web`.

Comment: @orad: If you have RC2 installed, you should be using ``dotnet run``, not ``dnx``.

Comment: @nate-barbettini worked! thanks. Is dnx residual of older versions? Can I uninstall it?

Comment: @orad: Yes, ``dnx`` is deprecated. You should be able to uninstall it. Btw, if this question/answer was helpful, mind upvoting? :)

Comment: @nateBarbettini for me this doesn't work. tried to set the sdk version in the global.json but still getting the same error. any other idea would be welcome

Comment: @gigi Try scaffolding a new project with `dotnet new` and see if that restores and compiles.

Comment: I have all the latest versions (I started with rc2 tooling) and I'm getting this error on our build server and locally when nuget restore is called (I have some older projects) and the new project system. Please send me a message on slack..

Comment: I solved using nuget.exe 3.5 beta. Now it works perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Adding Below Code Will Definitely solve your problem . I have gone through this error and reached this question but Answer above does fit to my scenario so i am adding an another answer that helped me -

See In my case we need to add EntityFrameworkCore.Tools and EntityFrameworkCore.Designin project.json
Code that was needed to be added in project .json

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": {
            "version": "1.0.0-*",
            "type": "build"
        }
    },
    "tools": {
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-*"
    }
}
```

Below is the second change that may help you

```
"frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dnx451",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying above steps, the issue is not resolved . Then I found out to install .NET Core - .NET Core runtime and framework (https://github.com/dotnet/cli) manually .

After installing, issue got resolved and make sure to map the node.js path in `tools->option->projects and solutions->External web tools`

[image]